# Как передать видеопоток от сервера в бразуер, используя html и js?

Tags: javascript, html5, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, http-server

Есть небольшой http сервер, на котором исполняется скрипт, покадрово берущей изображение с вебки, с помощью opencv и преобразующий их в поток байт.

Вопрос такой... Какие заголовки нужно использовать на стороне сервера, чтоб покадрово передавать видеопоток, взятый с веб камеры? Какие теги html и методы js нужно использовать, чтоб отобразить полученный видеопоток в браузере?

Нашел вот такой уториал https://m.habr.com/ru/post/172419/ , но для меня, как для новечка, не хватет пояснений.